# Get apache to serve on LAN

Tags: apache, ubuntu

So I have the newest versions of Ubuntu and Apache running. Apache works for localhost but I cannot figure out how to load it from my laptop on the same wireless network. I have tried a lot of different things and not sure which are even related or would help in diagnosing the problem. I am a complete Linux and networking noob. Thanks for helping!

EDIT: To clarify, Apache is running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apache is running on your laptop on localhost interface just type in your browser window: `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1`.

If you want to make your site available for the other hosts in your wireless network you have to run apache on your external IP address (can be displayed by `ifconfig` utility) using `Listen` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html). Then, if you do not use [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) use the binding address to access your site, otherwise use the virtual host names configured.

Comment: How do I use the binding address? I tried setting it to listen to 192.168.2.5. Should I try 72.200.xxx.xxx?

Comment: Run `ifconfig` then you'll see your external IP address(es). To run apache on specific IP address change `Listen` directive in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to `Listen my.ip.add.ress:80` if you want to run apache on all of your network interfaces use `Listen 80`. Don't forget to restart apache after config modification by `apachectl restart`

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. That is the one variable I didn't try, I was putting the Listen directive in httpd.conf. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server.  ifconfig  get the ip address. Go to your laptop and type the address into your web browser.

Comment: Does not work, it times out. I have tried 192.128.2.5 and my actual IP address, both time out. Pinged my IP address and it is active...

Comment: Is apache running? Have you tried turning it off and on again?  Also go into interfaces and set a static IP, might be worth a go.

Comment: Yeah apache is running and I get "it works!". How do I set a static IP? And what IP should I be attempting to connect to? 192.168.2.5 or 72.200.xxx.xxx? Or a different one?

Comment: You're going to connect to the internal IP address, as the external is only going though your router.   Google search setting static IP you edit your interfaces file.